# How to recover from a CA certificate compromission

Tags: certificate, sign, client-certificates, pki

I use a self-signed certificate for signing client certificates, and I have a procedure in place to replace this certificate in case the private key is compromised. Sadly, this means that all client certificates will be made invalid.

I'm working on implementing a [PKI](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Public_key_infrastructure) on my system, which means I could have a "cold" root certificate that is only used for issuing intermediate CAs, which in turn would be able to sign my client certificates.

So, in the perfect world with a solid PKI, how could I recover from an intermediate certificate private key compromission, without having my clients to re-sign all their certificates?

I mean, as of today with my single, self-signed certificate, I have no doubt I would have to ask all my clients to re-send a CSR and re-sign all certificates with a fresh new private key. And have them be blocked until their new certificate is signed.
But with a PKI, where I consider the root certificate non-compromised, it is possible to have a smooth transition to a new intermediate certificate? Smooth meaning, not interruption of service for my clients?

For instance, I could imagine signing their certificate with two intermediate certificates on two physically different machines, so that with one certificate revoked, the second signature would still hold. Am I correct?
Is there any "industry standards" on this matter?

Answer (score 1):

A proper implemented PKI didn't protect you from reissuing all certificates that are signed from the compromised CA. If the signing CA is compromised you have to revoke all certificates.
Dual signing didn't help, either the certificate is revoked or not.

In an windows domain you could for example use an Active Directory integrated CA and implemented auto enroll to the clients.
You could also implement a CA like letsencrypt in your enterprise.
Boulder - An ACME CA
https://github.com/letsencrypt/boulder